# Why are the community-specific close reasons not automatically included in the don't ask help article?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, help-center, custom-close-reasons, help-center-proposed

Any person can read a general pan-SE list of close reasons. Any person can read a site-specific list of on-topic areas – these are available in the help center. In a few SE sites, there is a list of "do not ask" type statements.

Every SE site apparently has the option of a community-specific close reason. However, it appears that the list of the 3 or more community-specific close reasons is not available to anyone except users with the power to VTC, in particular, it is not available to new users (who do not know to look through the Flag dialog).

Since there is (apparently) some database that states what the community-specific reasons are for e.g. Law, Linguistics, Academia, Philosophy, is there a reason (technical or philosophical) that the same **text cannot be automatically included** in the "don't ask" (the /help/dont-ask section) of each site's Help?

Comment: This is [the text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYUOG.jpg) referred to in this question; 2nd and 3rd grid.

Comment: The reasons are public. The list is available in the flag dialog to any user with the ability to *flag*, which takes 15 rep. IIRC, you can flag your own question, so it only takes posting your own question (1 rep). I believe they are also available from SEDE, which makes them available to anyone. The only difference between the close-vote dialog and the close-flag dialog is that the close-flag dialog has a "blatantly off-topic" reason, whereas the close-vote dialog instead has the ability to enter custom text for the reason, which is posted as a comment when the close-vote is submitted.

Comment: @Makyen, you both didn't read the question to the last paragraph; where the question is asked. I've made a tiny  edit clearly making the initial question obvious and show the URL of the Help.

Comment: @Rob There is an additional question which is asked in the last sentence, but it's based on a false premise which is stated in the question which is in the question title. It's fine to make a feature request asking for there to be a help center page which includes the reasons, but such a feature request should be based on accurate information.

Comment: Reread the request correctly.

Comment: This question has been closed for a network-related or community-specific reason. The question is off-topic or unanswerable. Please check the Help Center and try again.